# JavaScript: Global variable seems to be overwritten

Tags: javascript, global-variables, aframe, var

I'm currently working on the following code which should only save the first position. Anything detected afterwards should be ignored:

```
var markerPos;
var markerAlreadyDetected = false;

AFRAME.registerComponent('barcode_marker', {
    init: function () {
        const marker = document.querySelector('#marker');

        marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function () {
            console.log("Marker Already Detected:", markerAlreadyDetected);

            if (!markerAlreadyDetected) {
                markerAlreadyDetected = true;
                markerPos = marker.getAttribute('position');
                console.log("Saved new marker location.", markerPos);
            } else {
                console.log("Already detected marker.");
            }

            console.log("Saved marker position:", markerPos);
        });
    }
});
```

Eventhough the `if(!markerAlreadyDetected)` executes properly, the global variable seems to be changing everytime, the marker gets detected.

Here's some [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWUtD.png).

Comment: I think you are confusing your log messages. It seems to work exactly as it should.

Comment: Since `console.log("Saved marker position:", markerPos)` (line 19) outputs not the same coords everytime, `markerPos`seems to get changed. Which shouldn't happen.

Comment: You're assigning an object, which means it can change freely without you reassigning it. If you need to maintain a concrete state of the object, you need to make a clone of it or just take the primitive values you need from it.

Comment: @VLAZ That's it :) I saved the primitive values and it's working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This post was originally posted by [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) as a comment.

You're assigning an object, which means it can change freely without you reassigning it. If you need to maintain a concrete state of the object, you need to make a clone of it or just take the primitive values you need from it.